# Define a well structured answer.

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After wandering through the website some answers are unrealistically large. Do we have a guideline how to make a better readable well detailed answer?

If there is nothing as of now, what about adding it in the FAQ?

Answer (score 5):

I also noticed some questions are appearing too long. But that's just a subjective feeling and most of the answers I've seen are providing a summary at the top before diving into the details.

Here are three resources which might help in the future.

#### Check the help center on [how to answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

> - Make sure to answer the question
> - Always provide context for links
> - Write to the best of your ability
> - Only answer well-asked questions
> - Always be polite and have fun

#### Check meta stack exchange on [how to write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/226837).

> - Be clear.
> - Provide examples.
> - Link to more information and further reading.
> - Quote relevant material to keep the user from having to click on every link given to get basic information.
> - Revise your answer to include more information as it comes along.
> - Be sure to monitor your answer for comments so that you can reply with explanation if questions come around about your answer.

#### Check this block post by Jon Skeet on [how to answer technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/).

> - Read the question (carefully)
> - Code is king
> - Answer the question and highlight side-issues
> - It's okay to guess, but be honest
> - Raise the overall accuracy level
> - Provide links to related resources
> - Care about your reader: spelling, grammar and style matter
> - A time-limited answer may be better than no answer at all
> - Don't be afraid to delete (or edit heavily) useless answers
> - Be polite
> - Don't "answer and run"
> - Have fun

Comment: I think a "short answer" or tl;dr or summary is great, especially at the top, before a more detailed answer. I am stoked with longer answers, as long as they are organized and pertain to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I'm probably one of the guilty parties. Most recently with [Running a custom private go-ethereum node cluster using docker](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/running-a-custom-private-go-ethereum-node-cluster-using-docker) . I cannot answer the question adequately otherwise. I'll try to summarise at the beginning so no one has to read the details if they do not want to. And try to clean up afterwards.

Comment: Your answers, i am sure that it helpful for the OP to get an idea of the system. I personally read most of your answers and i like the way you write it. For a QA perspective its too much details. IMHO

Comment: Thx for the feedback @Nikhil.

Comment: You're welcome, i am happy that you took it very professionally. +1

Comment: I rather have too much details than 1-liners. :-)